# Timer that can be stopped and emits the elapsed time in qt

Tags: qt, timer, clock

I am looking for a clock/timer that can be started, stopped and can return the elpsed time since the start. Is there a widget that does all of these things?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`QTime`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtime.html) or [`QElapsedTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qelapsedtimer.html), but they are not `QObject`s, so you'll need to wrap them in a `QObject` class if you need to be able to start and stop them through Qt signals.

```
class Timer : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Timer(QObject *parent = 0): QObject(parent) {}    
public slots:
    void start() {
        time.start();
    }
    void stop() {
        emit elapsed(time.elapsed());
    }
signals:
    void elapsed(int msec);
private:
    QTime time;    
};
```

Comment: How would I do that? Do I need to make a new class that inherits a qelapsedtimer and define a stop() funtion?

Comment: I'd follow the "composition over inheritance" rule and make QElapsedTimer a member of your QObject-based wrapper. In case you need that at all - I don't see the need directly from your question.

Comment: I´m sorry, but I don´t get what you mean. Could you give an example of how I would be able to stop the QElapsedTimer this way?

Comment: @Frank Actually, these timers don't stop: they only store the starting time and the `elapsed()` function calculates the difference between the current time and that stored time.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this example, and also at the class [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html)

```
//This class will inherit from QTimer
class Timer : public QTimer
{
    //We will count all the time, that passed in miliseconds
    long timePassed;

    Q_OBJECT

    public:

    explicit Timer(QObject *parent = 0) : QTimer(parent)
    {
        timePassed = 0;
        connect(this, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tick()));
    }
    private slots:

    //this slot will be connected with the Timers timeout() signal.
    //after you start the timer, the timeout signal will be fired every time,
    //when the amount interval() time passed.
    void tick()
    {
        timePassed+=interval(); //we increase the time passed
        qDebug()<<timePassed; //and debug our collected time
    }
};
```

In your main application:

```
Timer * timer = new Timer(this);
timer->setInterval(1000);
timer->start();
```

This will create a Timer object, set its interval to 1 second, and start it. You can connect as many slots to the timeout() signal as you want, and you can create custom signals as well. You can stop the timer by `timer->stop();`

I hope it helped!

Comment: Seems more complicated to me than QTime/QElapsedTimer way, and also less accurate (there's no guarantee that a timer slot is called exactly after interval() - e.g. if another event handler takes a long time).